# Custom Authorize attribute not hitting breakpoint

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a custom authorize attribute like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public  void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var test = "break";

        /// pending...
        
    }
}
```

And I have added this attribute to my web api action method.
But when ever I try to get to the end point.. i get an unauthorized error, but it doesn't hit my breakpoint.

I have set my breakpoint at this line:

```
var test = "break";
```

Could somone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have created a asp.net core web api (.net 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `AuthorizeAttribute` to `Attribute`.

Please refer the following sample:

```
////required the following reference
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{


    /// <summary>  
    /// This will Authorize User  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns></returns>  
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {

        if (filterContext != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues authTokens;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("authToken", out authTokens);

            var _token = authTokens.FirstOrDefault();

            if (_token != null)
            {
                string authToken = _token;
                if (authToken != null)
                {
                    if (IsValidToken(authToken))
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("authToken", authToken);
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("AuthStatus", "Authorized");

                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("storeAccessiblity", "Authorized");

                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("authToken", authToken);
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("AuthStatus", "NotAuthorized");

                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Not Authorized";
                        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult("NotAuthorized")
                        {
                            Value = new
                            {
                                Status = "Error",
                                Message = "Invalid Token"
                            },
                        };
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Please Provide authToken";
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult("Please Provide authToken")
                {
                    Value = new
                    {
                        Status = "Error",
                        Message = "Please Provide authToken"
                    },
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidToken(string authToken)
    {
        //validate Token here  
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, apply the above custom attribute on the action method:

```
// GET api/<ToDoController>/5
[CustomAuthorization] 
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this is working for me now